# Big Theta with logarithmic function ${(log_{4} n )}^{2} \in \Theta(log_{2} (n^4))$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

Prove or disprove
${(log_{4} n )}^{2} \in \Theta(log_{2} (n^4))$
I do not know how to start here, thought it would be a good idea to convert them to the same base?
${(log_{4} n )}^{2} = {\left(\frac{ln  (n)}{ln (4)}\right)}^{2}$
and 
${log_{2}(n^4)}$ = $\frac{ln(n^4)}{ln(2)}$

However I do not know whether this approach is correct and what to do with what I have now.

Comment: $\operatorname{log}_2(n^4)=4\operatorname{log}_2(n)=\frac{4}{\operatorname{log}_4(2)}\operatorname{log}_4(n)$ so it reduces to whether $(\operatorname{log}_4(n))^2\in\Theta(\operatorname{log}_4(n))$.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(\log_{4} n) \in \Theta ( \log_2 n^4)$$ so intuition is that statement  is wrong.$(\log_4 n)^2$ grows much faster than $\log_2 n^4$.Now I will prove that $\log_2 n^4 \in \textbf{o} (\log_4 n)^2$ which proves that your proposition is wrong.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log_2 n^4 }{ (\log_4 n)^2} = 0$$

first note that $|\frac{\log_2 n^4}{(\log_4 n)^2}| = |\frac{4.\log_2 n}{ (\log_4 n) . (\log_4 n)}| \leq C \frac{1}{\log_4n}$ hence we have that limit is $0$ and your proposition is wrong

Comment: Thank you so much for your help